# Laravel filter one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm trying to filter a query on a model that has a one to many relationship, but it's not working. Correct output should remove all stocks that are expired, but it returns all the available stocks.

Product: hasMany(Stock::class)
Stock: belongsTo(Product::class)

code:

```
$keyword = $request->keyword;
$data = Product::with('stocks')
            ->where([
                ['pharmacy_id', '=', auth()->user()->pharmacy->id],
            ])
            ->where(function($productModel) use($keyword) {
                $productModel->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")->orWhere('sku', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
            })
            ->whereHas('stocks', function($stockModel) {
                $stockModel->where('expiry', '>', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
            })->get();
```

Current output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "sku": "xpzidfa1454995",
    "name": "Jaqueline Will",
    "category": "medicine",
    "type": "manufactured",
    "selling_price": "1.00",
    "pharmacy_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-12-22T11:40:32.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-22T11:40:32.000000Z",
    "stocks": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "product_id": 1,
        "expiry": "2025-10-10",
        "amount": 40,
        "supplier_id": 1,
        "pharmacy_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-12-22T11:45:39.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-22T11:45:39.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "product_id": 1,
        "expiry": "2020-10-10",
        "amount": 40,
        "supplier_id": 1,
        "pharmacy_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-12-22T11:45:39.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-22T11:45:39.000000Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Correct output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "sku": "xpzidfa1454995",
    "name": "Jaqueline Will",
    "category": "medicine",
    "type": "manufactured",
    "selling_price": "1.00",
    "pharmacy_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-12-22T11:40:32.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-22T11:40:32.000000Z",
    "stocks": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "product_id": 1,
        "expiry": "2025-10-10",
        "amount": 40,
        "supplier_id": 1,
        "pharmacy_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-12-22T11:45:39.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-22T11:45:39.000000Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Stock Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stock extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'expiry',
        'amount',
        'supplier_id',
        'pharmacy_id',
    ];

    public function pharmacy() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Pharmacy::class);
    }

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'll need to format the `Carbon` object within Laravel. Just use `Carbon::now()`

Comment: @Daan oh okay, didn't know that, thanks! It doesn't fix my issue though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the stock records which are expired, the constraint should be placed on the eager load

```php
$keyword = $request->keyword;
$data = Product::with(['stocks' => fn($query) => $query->whereDate('expiry', '>', now())])
    ->where([
        ['pharmacy_id', '=', auth()->user()->pharmacy->id],
    ])
    ->where(function($productModel) use($keyword) {
        $productModel->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")->orWhere('sku', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: This worked! Do you know if this is good for performance or not?

Comment: With eager loading, the problem of N+1 query is avoided. So eager loading is actually good for performance. Depending upon the context of your application and number of records for the Product model, you can use pagination instead of fetching all records

Answer (score 0):

I think you should match date using `whereDate`.

Try this,

```
$keyword = $request->keyword;
$data = Product::with('stocks')
            ->where([
                ['pharmacy_id', '=', auth()->user()->pharmacy->id],
            ])
            ->where(function($productModel) use($keyword) {
                $productModel->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")->orWhere('sku', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
            })
            ->whereHas('stocks', function($stockModel) {
                $stockModel->whereDate('expiry', '>', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
            })->get();
```

Check this link for more

[Laravel Additional Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Comment: I tried this, but it's still the same output

Comment: Then just use `now()`. Instead formatting date.

Comment: Still the same output. I'm guessing the chaining of the where clauses are wrong, but I can't arrive at the right way to do it.