# filter one to many relationship base on parent column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This  link  [Laravel filter one to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410666/laravel-filter-one-to-many-relationship) has a solution related to my question but I don't know why the solutions are not working for me.

I am currently selecting all the offtaker sites and the apartments the site have but I want to filter the apartment to only apartment that the apartment id is equal to the offtakers apartment_id
Below are my model setup

**offtaker model**

```
public function sites(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Sites::class,'site_id','id')->select('id','name');
}
```

**site model**

```
public function apartment(){
    return $this->hasMany(Apartment::class,'site_id','id');
   }
```

**offtaker controller**

```
return Offtakers::select(['id','site_id','offtaker_id','company_id','apartment_id'])
                   ->with('sites',
                        )->with('sites.apartment',function($query){
                            $query->where(function($query){
                                $query->whereRaw("id = (select apartment_id from offtakers where apartment_id=apartments.id)");
                            });
                        })->get();
```

**Current out put**

```
 {
        "id": 2,
        "site_id": "1",
        "offtaker_id": 6,
        "apartment_id": "8",
        "sites": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "first site",
            "apartment": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "company_id": 1,
                    "site_id": 1,
                    "project_id": null,
                    "apartment_name": "apartment five",
                    "apartment_description": "test descriptions",
                    "amount": 8000
                },
                {
                    "id": 55,
                    "company_id": 1,
                    "site_id": 1,
                    "project_id": null,
                    "apartment_name": "apartment eleven",
                    "apartment_description": "test descriptions",
                    "amount": 550000
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

**Expected out put**

```
 {
        "id": 2,
        "site_id": "1",
        "offtaker_id": 6,
        "apartment_id": "8",
        "sites": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "first site",
            "apartment": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "company_id": 1,
                    "site_id": 1,
                    "project_id": null,
                    "apartment_name": "apartment five",
                    "apartment_description": "test descriptions",
                    "amount": 8000
                },
               
            ]
        }
    },
```

Comment: can you please explain why inside Offtaker model there is id and offtaker_id ?

Comment: the id is the primary field on the offtaker table the offtaker_id is coming from another offtaker user table

Answer (score 0):

For you, I suggest you add this package https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep.

This will solve the 2 deep relationships Offtaker - Site - Apartment

Add new relationship in Offtaker model

```
public function apartments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Apartment::class, Site::class);
}
```

And to use it:

```
return Offtaker::select(['id','site_id','offtaker_id','company_id','apartment_id'])
  ->with([
     'sites' => function ($q) { 
         $q->where('id', 'offtakers.site_id');
     },
     'apartments' => function ($q) {
         $q
            ->where('site_id', 'offtakers.site_id')
            ->where('apartment_id', 'offtakers.apartment_id');
     }
  ])
  ->get();
```

However the result might a bit different that want you want

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "site_id": 1,
        "offtaker_id": 6,
        "apartment_id": 8,
        "sites": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "first site",
            }
         ],
         "apartments": [
            {
               "id": 8,
               "company_id": 1,
               "site_id": 1,
               "project_id": null,
               "apartment_name": "apartment five",
               "apartment_description": "test descriptions",
               "amount": 8000
           }               
        ]   
    },

    ....
```

I hope this can help you out.